# Image hover effect starting with a dark opaque background

Tags: image, hover, effect, rollover

I'm sorry if my title is vague I tried to give it some logic I dont know.

Anyway, so here is a site im working on (in progress)
http://art-williams.com/misc/index.html

and the 4 grid area as you can see, the zoom function is working great and also how it is dark low opacity then fades into full color. I like that.

But when the page loads they dont start with the dark low opacity, you have to roll over it first. Why is this?

Here is the code for the hover effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.viewport').mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '230', left: '-20', top: '-20', width: '490'}, 200);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeOut(400);
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '200', left: '0', top: '0', width: '450'}, 200);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: have you tried to remove this line `$(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(400);` ?

Comment: Yes, that just removes the span which is the dark-background all together.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood, you wanna all be dark when the page loads?

Comment: Yes thats exactly it, I want all the thumbnails to be dark then on rollover the dark fades and its full color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `$('.viewport').children('a').children('span').fadeIn(400);` after document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.viewport').children('a').children('span').fadeIn(400);
    $('.viewport').mouseenter(function(e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '230', left: '-20', top: '-20', width: '490'}, 200);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeOut(400);
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $(this).children('a').children('img').animate({ height: '200', left: '0', top: '0', width: '450'}, 200);
        $(this).children('a').children('span').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```